# How to generically solve polynomial expressions given a minimum value of x?

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus, polynomials

Given something like $\dfrac{8x^2 + 2x + 7}{3x^2 + 2x}$, and  $x > \sqrt8$, what strategy would you employ to simplify this expression?

Comment: Solve what?​​​​

Comment: excuse me, i mean simplify

Comment: @Rustyn: any reason you like \frac better than \dfrac here?

Comment: you can change it if you like

Comment: I'm honestly curious if you prefer the former or if it was a case of "last edit wins"...

Comment: I don't know, dfrac would be better here--it's hard to see frac

Comment: i think it's a case of digression...

Answer (score 1):

The top polynomial has no real roots, the bottom factors easily as $x(3x+2)$. Therefore these two polynomials have no common factors, so it's impossible to simplify further in that sense.

You could do long division of the numerator by the denominator and express the fraction as a constant plus $\frac{Ax+B}{3x^2+2x}$, for some $A$ and $B$, but overall I'd say this expression is already simple enough for most purposes.

I have absolutely no idea what you're supposed to do with the lower bound on $x$.

Answer (score 1):

First I would take

$$\frac {8x^2 + 2x + 7}{3x^2 + 2x}=2+\frac {2x^2-2x+7}{3x^2+2x}$$

(where I have subtracted $2\cdot\dfrac{3x^2+2x}{3x^2+2x}=2$).  By inspection, with $x\approx \sqrt 8=2\sqrt 2$ we have

$$2+\frac {23-4\sqrt 2}{24+4\sqrt 2}\lt 2+\frac {18}{29}\lt 2+\frac {18}{27}=\frac 83$$

We also have

$$\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac {8x^2 + 2x + 7}{3x^2 + 2x}=\frac 83$$

Then I would consider another value like $x=1$ which yields $\dfrac {17}5=3\dfrac 25$.  Now I know that $x=\sqrt 8$ may be near a local minimum, and since the expression involves polynomials of degree $2$ with positive leading coefficients, I can be certain that

$$x\in(\sqrt 8,\infty)\implies \frac {8x^2 + 2x + 7}{3x^2 + 2x}\in\left(2+\frac{23-4\sqrt 2}{24+4\sqrt 2}, \frac 83\right)$$

But none of this really simplifies the original expression, it merely gives some bounds on what the value could be...

One other approach would be to consider how the expression could be modified to have real or rational roots in the numerator.  To that end, consider the following:

$$\frac{8x^2+2x+7}{3x^2+2x}=\frac{(8+3u)x^2+(2+2u)x+7}{3x^2+2x}-u$$

Then we have solutions

$$\begin{align}x&=\frac {-2-2u\pm\sqrt{4+8u+4u^2-28\cdot 8-28\cdot 3u}}{16+6u}\\\\
&=\frac{-1-u\pm\sqrt{u^2-19u-55}}{8+3u}
\end{align}$$

Since the square root term has a quadratic with obvious positive and negative portions, it would be beneficial to solve this one as well:

$$u=\frac {19\pm\sqrt{361+220}}{2}\\\\
\approx \frac {19}2\pm 12.052\approx -2.552,21.552$$

These are not particularly useful as results go, but they do demonstrate the range of values for $u$ for which there are real solutions for $x$.  With a little bit of searching, it is possible to find that $u\in\{-13,32\}$ in fact yields rational solutions for $x$ as follows:

$$u=-13,x=\frac{-1-u\pm\sqrt{u^2-19u-55}}{8+3u}=-1,\frac 7{31}\\\\
u=32,x=-\frac 12,-\frac 7{52}$$

Taking $u=-13$ we get

$$\begin{align}\frac{8x^2+2x+7}{3x^2+2x}&=\frac {-31x^2-24x+7}{3x^2+2x}+13\\\\
&=13-\frac {(31x-7)(x+1)}{x(3x+2)}\end{align}$$

This is also only marginally simpler relative to the original and begs the question "what is expected to be found?"

Answer (score 0):

$$\dfrac{8x^2 + 2x + 7}{3x^2 + 2x}= \dfrac{2x^2}{3x^2+2x}+\dfrac{3x^2}{3x^2+2x}+\dfrac{3x^2 + 2x }{3x^2 + 2x}+\frac{7}{3x^2+2x}$$

If$x>\sqrt{8}>1$
Then
$$\dfrac{8x^2 + 2x + 7}{3x^2 + 2x} < \frac{2}{5} + \frac{3}{5}+1+\frac{7}{5} = \frac{17}{5}$$